# Get append control value from code behind in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, append, clone

I have a div that contains multiple hidden field which generate by using jquery `.append()`

```
function add(ctr)
{
    $('.divContainer').append(ctr.clone());
}
```

In the client side i will have something like

```
<div class="divContainer">
  <div class="dynamicCtr">
    <input type="hidden" name="hf_1" id="_1" value="4515">
  </div>
  <div class="dynamicCtr">
    <input type="hidden" name="hf_2" id="_2" value="4422">
  </div>
</div>
```

All the controls inside divContainer are clone by using jquery.

I tried below but doesn't work.

```
HtmlControl divHave = this.divHave;

    foreach (Control control in divHave.Controls)
    {
        if (control is HtmlInputHidden)
        {
            HtmlInputHidden hf = (HtmlInputHidden)control;
            Response.Write("Value :" + hf.Value);
        }
    }
```

Is there any way i can access all the hidden field within the divContainer from code behind?

Answer (score 0):

When you postback, every cloned divs by jquery are lost by server.

Try to use

```
<asp:Panel ID="divHave" runat="server">
    <!-- resolves to a DIV -->
</asp:Panel>
```

And insert div at server side with Ajax

```
HtmlGenericControl div = HtmlGenericControl("div")
div.Id = "myid";
divHave.Controls.Add(div);
```